# jvm crash in 8.0_121-b13

Tags: java, jvm

Our production servers crashed twice with problematic frame inside one of our classes. We have not been able to reproduce this issue and haven't seen it in any other environment. What can cause this?

how to play..........

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32744 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:273), pid=3304, tid=0x000000000000139c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. 
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000005507a000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5020, stack(0x0000000056180000,0x0000000056280000)]

Stack: [0x0000000056180000,0x0000000056280000]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing stack bounds), id 0xc0000005]

Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)


Current CompileTask:
C2:4318067 19033       4       org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener::convertCacheEntryToEntity (533 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000059d16000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4116, stack(0x0000000077170000,0x0000000077270000)]
  0x0000000059d1a800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4964, stack(0x00000000774e0000,0x00000000775e0000)]
  0x0000000059d19800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5780, stack(0x0000000076e60000,0x0000000076f60000)]
  0x0000000058980000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4112, stack(0x0000000076fe0000,0x00000000770e0000)]
  0x0000000058980800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5732, stack(0x0000000076d10000,0x0000000076e10000)]
  0x0000000058982000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4772, stack(0x0000000072ad0000,0x0000000072bd0000)]
  0x000000005897f000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5068, stack(0x0000000072d00000,0x0000000072e00000)]
  0x0000000058981800 JavaThread "Dispatch-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@71c1d887" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6052, stack(0x0000000075700000,0x0000000075800000)]
  0x0000000058983000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3080, stack(0x0000000073a60000,0x0000000073b60000)]
  0x0000000058983800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4996, stack(0x0000000073c20000,0x0000000073d20000)]
  0x000000005897e800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2864, stack(0x0000000073910000,0x0000000073a10000)]
  0x0000000059d17800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2724, stack(0x00000000765f0000,0x00000000766f0000)]
  0x0000000059d19000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6040, stack(0x0000000076b40000,0x0000000076c40000)]
  0x0000000059d18000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4916, stack(0x00000000769e0000,0x0000000076ae0000)]
  0x0000000059d14800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5176, stack(0x00000000760c0000,0x00000000761c0000)]
  0x0000000059d15000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1104, stack(0x0000000076470000,0x0000000076570000)]
  0x000000005897b800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2916, stack(0x0000000075fc0000,0x00000000760c0000)]
  0x0000000058979000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3548, stack(0x0000000075e00000,0x0000000075f00000)]
  0x000000005897d000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4092, stack(0x0000000073680000,0x0000000073780000)]
  0x000000005897a800 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5456, stack(0x0000000072ea0000,0x0000000072fa0000)]
  0x000000005897c000 JavaThread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5188, stack(0x0000000075a90000,0x0000000075b90000)]
  0x0000000058978800 JavaThread "Dispatch-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@702d98be" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2932, stack(0x0000000075850000,0x0000000075950000)]
  0x000000005ac66000 JavaThread "executor-10" [_thread_blocked, id=5052, stack(0x0000000075970000,0x0000000075a70000)]
  0x000000005ac65800 JavaThread "executor-9" [_thread_blocked, id=2476, stack(0x00000000753f0000,0x00000000754f0000)]
  0x000000005ac64800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=804, stack(0x00000000749e0000,0x0000000074ae0000)]
  0x000000005ac64000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4540, stack(0x0000000061c50000,0x0000000061d50000)]
  0x000000005ac63000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5892, stack(0x0000000075210000,0x0000000075310000)]
  0x0000000059d23800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6084, stack(0x0000000075100000,0x0000000075200000)]
  0x0000000059d22800 JavaThread "executor-8" [_thread_blocked, id=6140, stack(0x0000000074f30000,0x0000000075030000)]
  0x0000000059d22000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5212, stack(0x0000000066180000,0x0000000066280000)]
  0x0000000059d20800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4732, stack(0x0000000074e00000,0x0000000074f00000)]
  0x0000000059d21000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4712, stack(0x00000000748e0000,0x00000000749e0000)]
  0x0000000059d1f800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3464, stack(0x00000000747d0000,0x00000000748d0000)]
  0x0000000059d1f000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3444, stack(0x00000000741b0000,0x00000000742b0000)]
  0x0000000059d1e000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3512, stack(0x0000000074440000,0x0000000074540000)]
  0x0000000059d1d800 JavaThread "executor-7" [_thread_blocked, id=4924, stack(0x0000000056080000,0x0000000056180000)]
  0x0000000059d1c800 JavaThread "executor-6" [_thread_blocked, id=5772, stack(0x0000000074300000,0x0000000074400000)]
  0x0000000059d1c000 JavaThread "executor-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3124, stack(0x000000006d810000,0x000000006d910000)]
  0x00000000653ec000 JavaThread "executor-4" [_thread_blocked, id=312, stack(0x0000000073090000,0x0000000073190000)]
  0x00000000653ea800 JavaThread "executor-3" [_thread_blocked, id=636, stack(0x0000000073780000,0x0000000073880000)]
  0x00000000653eb000 JavaThread "executor-2" [_thread_blocked, id=544, stack(0x000000006dc00000,0x000000006dd00000)]
  0x0000000059d1b000 JavaThread "executor-1" [_thread_blocked, id=264, stack(0x0000000073eb0000,0x0000000073fb0000)]
  0x0000000059cf1800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5480, stack(0x00000000729c0000,0x0000000072ac0000)]
  0x0000000059cf0800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3184, stack(0x0000000070d30000,0x0000000070e30000)]
  0x0000000059cef800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2760, stack(0x0000000072750000,0x0000000072850000)]
  0x0000000059cef000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3640, stack(0x000000006f450000,0x000000006f550000)]
  0x0000000059cee000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3180, stack(0x0000000070bd0000,0x0000000070cd0000)]
  0x0000000056f02000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5408, stack(0x0000000070ab0000,0x0000000070bb0000)]
  0x0000000056f01000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2960, stack(0x0000000070740000,0x0000000070840000)]
  0x0000000056f00800 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5032, stack(0x000000006fb40000,0x000000006fc40000)]
  0x0000000056eff800 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=1168, stack(0x000000006f950000,0x000000006fa50000)]
  0x0000000056eff000 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=5412, stack(0x000000006f760000,0x000000006f860000)]
  0x00000000571b9000 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=5896, stack(0x000000006f5b0000,0x000000006f6b0000)]
  0x00000000571b8000 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=3116, stack(0x000000006e940000,0x000000006ea40000)]
  0x00000000571b7800 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=2416, stack(0x000000006f320000,0x000000006f420000)]
  0x00000000571b6800 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=2052, stack(0x000000006f170000,0x000000006f270000)]
  0x00000000571b6000 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3660, stack(0x000000006f000000,0x000000006f100000)]
  0x00000000636d7000 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3992, stack(0x000000006eed0000,0x000000006efd0000)]
  0x00000000636d6800 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=5416, stack(0x000000006ed60000,0x000000006ee60000)]
  0x00000000636d5800 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=976, stack(0x000000006eb70000,0x000000006ec70000)]
  0x00000000636d5000 JavaThread "schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5724, stack(0x000000006ea40000,0x000000006eb40000)]
  0x00000000636d4000 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5276, stack(0x000000006e770000,0x000000006e870000)]
  0x000000005ade5000 JavaThread "scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=3340, stack(0x000000006e570000,0x000000006e670000)]
  0x00000000653ed800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2260, stack(0x000000006e1f0000,0x000000006e2f0000)]
  0x00000000653ec800 JavaThread "com%002ejeecms%002ecore%002esecurity%002e%0043ms%0041uthorizing%0052ealm%002eauthorization%0043ache.data" [_thread_blocked, id=4896, stack(0x000000006dfc0000,0x000000006e0c0000)]
  0x00000000653e9800 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5360, stack(0x000000006d950000,0x000000006da50000)]
  0x00000000653e9000 JavaThread "com%002ejeecms%002ecore%002eentity%002e%0043ms%0055ser%002elogs.data" [_thread_blocked, id=5844, stack(0x000000006d360000,0x000000006d460000)]
  0x00000000653e8000 JavaThread  
  0x000000005adeb000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5644, stack(0x0000000063e00000,0x0000000063f00000)]
  0x000000005adea800 JavaThread "com%002ejeecms%002ecms%002eentity%002eassist%002e%0043ms%0056ote%0052eply.data" [_thread_blocked, id=5172, stack(0x00000000644b0000,0x00000000645b0000)]
  0x000000005ade9800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3356, stack(0x0000000064260000,0x0000000064360000)]
  0x000000005ade9000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3724, stack(0x0000000064130000,0x0000000064230000)]
  0x000000005ade8000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5224, stack(0x0000000063f40000,0x0000000064040000)]
  0x000000005ade7800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3136, stack(0x0000000063d00000,0x0000000063e00000)]
  0x000000005ade6800 JavaThread "org%002ehibernate%002ecache%002einternal%002e%0053tandard%0051uery%0043ache.data" [_thread_blocked, id=3396, stack(0x0000000062c30000,0x0000000062d30000)]
  0x000000005ade6000 JavaThread "org%002ehibernate%002ecache%002espi%002e%0055pdate%0054imestamps%0043ache.data" [_thread_blocked, id=5744, stack(0x000000005df70000,0x000000005e070000)]

  0x000000005b4c4000 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@30f61e1d" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5236, stack(0x000000005e0b0000,0x000000005e1b0000)]
  0x00000000571d3000 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1332, stack(0x0000000057440000,0x0000000057540000)]
  0x000000005734d800 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=712, stack(0x0000000058cf0000,0x0000000058df0000)]
  0x0000000056ec8000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2068, stack(0x00000000566c0000,0x00000000567c0000)]
  0x00000000563d4800 JavaThread "AsyncFileHandlerWriter-929338653" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3360, stack(0x0000000056b40000,0x0000000056c40000)]
  0x0000000056297000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3268, stack(0x00000000567e0000,0x00000000568e0000)]
  0x00000000550cb800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2248, stack(0x0000000055840000,0x0000000055940000)]
=>0x000000005507a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5020, stack(0x0000000056180000,0x0000000056280000)]
  0x0000000055079000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1164, stack(0x0000000055a60000,0x0000000055b60000)]
  0x000000005508d000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3516, stack(0x0000000055f80000,0x0000000056080000)]
  0x0000000055048800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3544, stack(0x0000000055d80000,0x0000000055e80000)]
  0x0000000055005000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4188, stack(0x0000000055bd0000,0x0000000055cd0000)]
  0x00000000025ff800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2424, stack(0x00000000028a0000,0x00000000029a0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000054ffd000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000055950000,0x0000000055a50000] [id=3160]
  0x00000000562c9800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000056960000,0x0000000056a60000] [id=5560]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000025fdca0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000054ffd000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 325632K, used 165084K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fec80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 323584K, 50% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f4a672b0,0x00000000fe700000)
  from space 2048K, 90% used [0x00000000fea80000,0x00000000fec50000,0x00000000fec80000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fe880000,0x00000000fe880000,0x00000000fea80000)
 ParOldGen       total 155136K, used 100497K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c9780000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 155136K, 64% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c6224720,0x00000000c9780000)
 Metaspace       used 80452K, capacity 84083K, committed 84928K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 8658K, capacity 9289K, committed 9472K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011d60000,0x0000000011f70000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011760000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00000000716bb6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000124d0000, 0x00000000134d0000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000134d0000, 0x00000000144d0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000130000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=55299Kb max_used=55513Kb free=190461Kb
 bounds [0x00000000029a0000, 0x0000000006030000, 0x00000000119a0000]
 total_blobs=15443 nmethods=14730 adapters=624
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 4209.671 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 nmethod 19028 0x0000000003a22690 code [0x0000000003a227e0, 0x0000000003a22970]
Event: 4209.707 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 19029       3       org.quartz.utils.ClassUtils::isAnnotationPresentOnSuperClasses (68 bytes)
Event: 4209.707 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 nmethod 19029 0x00000000034e5b90 code [0x00000000034e5d80, 0x00000000034e6668]
Event: 4209.760 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 19030       3       org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes::<init> (5 bytes)
Event: 4209.761 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 nmethod 19030 0x0000000004995dd0 code [0x0000000004995f40, 0x00000000049960c8]
Event: 4209.775 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 19031   !   3       org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.regions.EhcacheGeneralDataRegion::put (86 bytes)
Event: 4209.776 Thread 0x00000000550cb800 nmethod 19031 0x0000000003c639d0 code [0x0000000003c63c00, 0x0000000003c64888]
Event: 4209.843 Thread 0x000000005507a000 19032       4       org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener::postLoadEventListeners (36 bytes)
Event: 4209.860 Thread 0x000000005507a000 nmethod 19032 0x0000000006023fd0 code [0x0000000006024280, 0x0000000006024cc8]
Event: 4209.864 Thread 0x000000005507a000 19033       4       org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener::convertCacheEntryToEntity (533 bytes)

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4049.872 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1082 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 300032K, used 299744K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fd480000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 298496K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fce80000,0x00000000fce80000)
  from space 1536K, 81% used [0x00000000fd300000,0x00000000fd438000,0x00000000fd480000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd280000)
 ParOldGen       total 155136K, used 100489K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c9780000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 155136K, 64% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c6222720,0x00000000c9780000)
 Metaspace       used 80442K, capacity 84077K, committed 84928K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 8658K, capacity 9288K, committed 9472K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 4049.879 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1082 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 302592K, used 1408K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fec80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 300544K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fd080000)
  from space 2048K, 68% used [0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd1e0000,0x00000000fd280000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fea80000,0x00000000fea80000,0x00000000fec80000)
 ParOldGen       total 155136K, used 100489K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c9780000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 155136K, 64% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c6222720,0x00000000c9780000)
 Metaspace       used 80442K, capacity 84077K, committed 84928K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 8658K, capacity 9288K, committed 9472K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 4079.948 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1083 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 302592K, used 301952K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fec80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 300544K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd080000)
  from space 2048K, 68% used [0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd1e0000,0x00000000fd280000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fea80000,0x00000000fea80000,0x00000000fec80000)
 ParOldGen       total 155136K, used 100489K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c9780000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 155136K, 64% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c6222720,0x00000000c9780000)
 Metaspace       used 80442K, capacity 84077K, committed 84928K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 8658K, capacity 9288K, committed 9472K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 4079.958 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1083 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 325632K, used 1856K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fec80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 323584K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fe700000)
  from space 2048K, 90% used [0x00000000fea80000,0x00000000fec50000,0x00000000fec80000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fe880000,0x00000000fe880000,0x00000000fea80000)
 ParOldGen       total 155136K, used 100497K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c9780000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 155136K, 64% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c6224720,0x00000000c9780000)
 Metaspace       used 80442K, capacity 84077K, committed 84928K, reserved 1124352K
  class space    used 8658K, capacity 9288K, committed 9472K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 4000.892 Thread 0x0000000059d22000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000518e500 method=org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Anno
Event: 4000.892 Thread 0x0000000059d22000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002af3c78 method=java.lang.ref.SoftReference.get()Ljava/lang/Object; @ 6
Event: 4000.892 Thread 0x0000000059d22000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000518e500 method=org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Anno
Event: 4000.892 Thread 0x0000000059d22000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000518e500 method=org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Anno
Event: 4000.893 Thread 0x0000000059d22000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000004d2b214 method=org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Anno
Event: 4000.920 Thread 0x0000000059d22000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000435b84c method=java.lang.ref.SoftReference.get()Ljava/lang/Object; @ 6
Event: 4001.371 Thread 0x000000005ac63000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000005a136a4 method=java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.offer(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Z @ 39
Event: 4035.113 Thread 0x000000005add0800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000004c29518 method=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(I)V @ 19
Event: 4209.730 Thread 0x000000005ac63000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000005253c0c method=java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Z)V @ 31
Event: 4209.730 Thread 0x000000005ac63000 Uncommon trap: reason=unloaded action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003aa4118 method=org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(Z)Z @ 270

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 4205.040 Thread 0x000000005897a800 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa1b838) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.043 Thread 0x0000000059d19000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa26b28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.045 Thread 0x000000005897b800 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000ef9fd718) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.048 Thread 0x0000000059d15000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa353c0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.050 Thread 0x000000005897d000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa04090) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.052 Thread 0x0000000059d18000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa3d5b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.054 Thread 0x0000000058979000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa0ad58) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.056 Thread 0x0000000059d14800 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa4a258) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.056 Thread 0x000000005897c000 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa14cc8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 4205.056 Thread 0x0000000059d17800 Exception <a 'java/net/ConnectException': Connection timed out: connect> (0x00000000efa54d50) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]

Events (10 events):
Event: 4209.842 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 4209.842 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 4209.842 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 4209.842 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 4209.843 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 4209.861 Thread 0x000000005507a000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000005a612d0
Event: 4209.862 Thread 0x000000005507a000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000005c09550
Event: 4209.862 Thread 0x000000005507a000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000005c4fed0
Event: 4209.863 Thread 0x000000005507a000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000005e39bd0
Event: 4209.902 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias

  ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23572)

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 79 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, tsc, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 4193784k(415244k free), swap 4191924k(123832k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sat May 06 15:33:04 2017
elapsed time: 4317 seconds (0d 1h 11m 57s)
```

Comment: You appear to have 10% free physical memory and 2% free swap memory.  I would *think* that the "out of memory" error that you receive is believable.  But let's see what others say.

Comment: hs_error file is truncated, need to know the vm arguments, you running oom, vm arguments are required to know in which area you have issue?

Comment: "What can cause this?" - the message states so itself *"# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space"*

Comment: You appear to have plenty of free memory. Even though Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 is listed as a supported OS for Java 8, it reached end of mainline support in Jan 2015, I would suspect a bug in the OS. esp if you can't reproduce it on other systems.

Comment: @the8472 at the end, the dump states `Memory: 4k page, physical 4193784k(415244k free), swap 4191924k(123832k free)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey that means 97% of the page file and 90% of physical is full. That smells fishy. Windows has no overcommit, so there may also be a discrepancy of commited-but-unused, essentially occupying the remaining parts. Which would make the system commit charge exceeding the available pools.

Comment: thank you all，There is not enough physical memory space